# Git push/pull: error en autenticación para realizar push/pull

Tags: git, github

Error al tratar de realizar git push/pull: "La autenticación de contraseña está temporalmente deshabilitada como parte de un apagón."[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que sería recomendable que utilizaras ssh como transporte, en vez de https.

Comment: Esto tiene un thread enorme en SO en ingles.. [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68191392/73749)

Comment: Debes generar el token, complementando la respuesta de @x-rw, puedes usar tu username y en password le pasas el token generado

Comment: @Daniel puedes poner tu respuesta porfavor, tu comentario queda corto

Answer (score 4):

debes generar un nuevo token: aqui los pasos https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

elimina el control al origin localmente

```
 git remote remove origin
```

agregalo de nuevo pero ahora con tu token generado

```
git remote add origin https://<token>@<git_url>.git
```

y enpujalo

```
git pull https://<token>@<git_url>.git
```

**nota**:

que es git_url? es la url de tu proyecto actual
ejemplo: `github.com/yourUser/yourProy`

y borra los caracteres <>

Answer (score 4):

Hola a mi me sucedió lo mismo hoy. Además de lo que te dice el compañero x-rw de generar un `token` en GitHub [aquí](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). No hace falta hacer todo eso, al menos si estas en un Mac.
Puedes hacer lo siguiente, así no hace falta quitar la conexión remota y volverla a ponerla y más si te paso como a mi en medio de un commit.

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Answer (score 1):

complementando la respuesta de @x-rw, puedes usar tu token como password, al hacer eso, ya podras usar tu password normalmente sin problemas, eso a mi me funciono haciendo un git pull en docker

```
 PS /home/project/project> git pull
    Username for 'https://github.com': username@gmail.com
    Password for 'https://username@github.com':  ghp_L13itokenexample 
    //aqui tu token
    Already up to date.
    PS /home/project/project>
```